# lua-lanes in luajit2

Tags: lua, luajit, lua-lanes

Is there a way to use [lanes](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/) library inside [luajit 2](http://luajit.org/) ?

As far as I got, there is a limitation in luajit that [lua_dump()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_dump) c-api function is not supported. Is there some other way to get code chunk of given function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maintainer of Lanes recently wrote [this message](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-04/msg00398.html) about LuaJIT2 status; summary: it's not working yet.

That same thread has some links to [lua-llthreads](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-llthreads) and [lua-zmq](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-zmq) that work with LuaJIT2 and may be of interest to you.

Comment: It seams that LuaJIT 2.0.0-beta8 version has support for bytecode loading/saving.

Answer (score 9):

Status update:   I happened to be looking into the same issue recently.

From the lua-list a few days ago:  Lanes 3.0 beta is out, and supporting LuaJIT 2

[link to announcement](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-11/msg00182.html)